# How can I Sort my Products(items) in firebaserecyclerAdapter

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I am trying to sort my data(Products) in different filters e.g. sort alphabetically, sort by price, sort by date.

The data is fetched from firebase Realtime Database In Node:
[image: The data is fetched from firebase Realtime Database In Node (Image is attached)]

I already have used **orderByChild** Method, but the problem is that it filters data not sort data.

```
    //recycelrView Setup for Product Listing
        gridLayoutManager_categ = new GridLayoutManager(this, 2);
        rv_categ.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager_categ);
        rv_categ.setHasFixedSize(true);

//FirebaseRecyclerAdapter for fetching data from firebase and showing it into recylerview

    databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Products").child(rootText);
        categ_options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Products>().setQuery(databaseReference, Products.class).build();
        categ_Adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Products, MyViewHolder_categAdapter>(categ_options) {
            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final MyViewHolder_categAdapter Holder, int i, @NonNull final Products products) {
                

            }

            @NonNull
            @Override
            public MyViewHolder_categAdapter onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                View view= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.product_layout,parent,false);
                return new MyViewHolder_categAdapter(view);
            }
        };
        categ_Adapter.startListening();
        rv_categ.setAdapter(categ_Adapter);

   }
```

If it is not possible in this case then please suggest me any other method to show my products like this. (like using any other database or method etc.)

Answer (score 0):

If `databaseReference` points to the `Ghee` node in your screenshot, you can get a query that orders the child nodes on the value of `productPrice` with:

```
Query query = databaReference.orderByChild("productPrice");
```

You can then pass the query to the adapter options:

```
categ_options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Products>().setQuery(query, Products.class).build();
```

Comment: Hi Frank, Thanks for considering. Actually I am using the solution already that you suggested. I want to Order My Products with alphabatically A-Z or Z-A.

Comment: The code you shared doesn't order on anything yet. Please make sure that your question contains the code that you're asking about.

Comment: Hi Frank, I am sorry for late reply. Actually I don't have a code to order products. I want to know a method to order items. Thanks